# Is Mathematica's (v10.0.2) NetCDF exporter broken?

Tags: export, data

I'm trying something very simple, namely:

```
Export["file.nc", {"Datasets" -> {"seqs" -> {"AAA", "BBB"}}}, "Rules"]
```

And getting Java errors about "illegal Datatype for netcdf-3 format".

I'm observing this behavior on Windows and OS X. Am I making a mistake or is the NetCDF exporter broken?

I have no trouble importing strings. Specifying that "DataFormat" be "String" explicitly does not help.

Comment: I believe that in accordance with standard practice, the other, [Exporting String to NetCDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113613/exporting-string-to-netcdf), should have been marked a duplicate of this, since this Q&A is older.

Answer (score 2):

NetCDF does not support primitive `String` type variables as indicated [here](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/BestPractices.html#Strings%20and%20Variables%20of%20type%20char) due to the variable length of `String`.
As such, the way dealing with `String`s by NetCDF is to store them as `Char`-type variables and then convert them back as strings wherever needed.

However, Mathematica doesn't have a primitive `Char` type and thus cannot export `Datasets` with `Char`-type content directly.
A workaround for you might be converting `string`s to character code arrays  (i.e.`ToCharacterCode`) first and getting them back (i.e. `FromCharacterCode`) for later use.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding NetCDF's limitations. Still, Mathematica does automatically convert Char arrays to strings upon import, and the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NetCDF.html) explicitly states that `"String"` is an acceptable option for `"DataFormat"`, without making a distinction between importing and exporting. At a minimum this is a fault in the documentation.