# Exporting String to NetCDF

Tags: export

I've already read a Q&A stating that because NetCDF does not support primitive string type variables, that it is impossible to export a string to a NetCDF file.

For example:

`testvalsnodvar = {"VOL_FRACTION01"};
Export["W:\\LPF_extractor\\test.nc", {"vals_nod_var" ->testvalsnodvar}, "Datasets"]`

gives a Java error stating that this is an incorrect format for Datasets. Is there a way around this or am I stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Mathematica's (v10.0.2) NetCDF exporter broken?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/is-mathematicas-v10-0-2-netcdf-exporter-broken)

Comment: This one can't be closed as a duplicate until the other one is reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the string to a list of integers using [`ToCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode.html), and then convert back using [`FromCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCharacterCode.html).

```
testvalsnodvar = {"VOL_FRACTION01"};
Export["test.nc", {"vals_nod_var" -> 
   ToCharacterCode@testvalsnodvar}, "NetCDF"]
(* "test.nc" *)

Import[
  "test.nc", {"Datasets", "vals_nod_var"}] // FromCharacterCode
(* {"VOL_FRACTION01"} *)
```

Comment: That works great for working strictly in Mathematica, however, reading this into another program does not work so well. I suppose there is no way around it if my only option is to convert strings into ASCII code.

Comment: From what [this](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2010/bestpractices/Strings.html) page says strings are not a natively supported data type.

Answer (score 1):

No need for workarounds in WL 13.1+:

```
In[1]:= Export["test.nc", "vals_nod_var" -> {"VOL_FRACTION01"}]

Out[1]= "test.nc"

In[2]:= Import["test.nc", "vals_nod_var"]

Out[2]= {"VOL_FRACTION01"}
```

By default, Export chooses netCDF-4 format for the file:

```
In[3]:= Import["test.nc", "Version"]

Out[3]= "NC4 Enhanced"
```

If you need to Export a string to the classic netCDF data model it will still work, but the string will be exported as an array of characters, thus adding one dimension:

```
In[4]:= Export["test.nc", "vals_nod_var" -> {"VOL_FRACTION01"}, "Version" -> "Classic"]

Out[4]= "test.nc"

In[5]:= Import["test.nc", "vals_nod_var"]

Out[5]= {{"V", "O", "L", "_", "F", "R", "A", "C", "T", "I", "O", "N", "0", "1"}}
```